# Static linking with PreMake

Tags: c++, build, premake

First of all sorry for my bad english.

i am trying to link raylib.

Windows 10
PreMake version 5.0
g++ version 8.1.0

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrgKG.png)

````
    // premake5.lua
    workspace "foo"
        architecture "x64"
        configurations {"Debug","Release"}
        outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.architecture}-%{cfg.system}"
    
    project "foo"
        location "./build/"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"
        targetdir "./build/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
        files { "./src/**.cpp",
        "./src/**.c",
        "./dependencies/**.h"
        }
        includedirs {"./dependencies/**"}
        links{"raylib"}
        libdirs{"./dependencies/**"}
    
    
    
        filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
    
        filter "configurations:Release"
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        optimize "On

"```
````

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <raylib.h>
int main(){
    const int screenWidth = 800;

    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib [core] example - basic window");

    SetTargetFPS(60);            


    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

            DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);

        EndDrawing();
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

  
    CloseWindow();
  

    return 0;
```

}```

error message:
Linking Mew
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(core.o):core.c:(.text+0x14dcd): undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod' ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(core.o):core.c:(.text+0x167ca): undefined reference to` timeBeginPeriod'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x16fa): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'     ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x1736): undefined reference to` __imp_DeleteObject'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x1791): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'       ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x21ce): undefined reference to` __imp_GetDeviceCaps'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x27ff): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'         ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x2813): undefined reference to` __imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x281c): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC' ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6154): undefined reference to` __imp_CreateDCW'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6183): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'     ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x619c): undefined reference to` __imp_DeleteDC'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6308): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'     ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x633e): undefined reference to` __imp_GetDeviceCaps'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6539): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'  ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6573): undefined reference to` __imp_CreateBitmap'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x660b): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'      ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x6660): undefined reference to` __imp_DeleteObject'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x7e89): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'         ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x7e98): undefined reference to` __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x7ea1): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC' ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xdcb2): undefined reference to` __imp_ChoosePixelFormat'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xdcc0): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'    ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xe159): undefined reference to` __imp_DescribePixelFormat'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xe251): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat' ../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xe61d): undefined reference to` __imp_DescribePixelFormat'
../dependencies/raylib/lib/libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xe63c): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:78: Debug/Mew.exe] Error 1

Thank you and also forgive me for my English.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit late but I'll try. While compiling on Windows you need to add link libraries dependencies explicitely, especially the windows ones.
What you described are link errors. To solve the linkage problem, you have to add to link dependencies some libraries: opengl32.lib, gdi32.lib, user32.lib, ole32.lib, and optional: [netapi32.lib, Wininet.lib]

The __imp_SetPixelFormat, __imp_DescribePixelFormat, __imp_ChoosePixelFormat are defined in gdi32.lib
The __imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp is defined in opengl.lib
The __imp_DeleteObject, __imp_CreateDCW, __imp_SwapBuffers, __imp_DeleteDC are defined in the user32.lib

Hope it is useful.

PS: for runtime, make sure you have the correct redistributable (dlls).